# getting *.php to run *.aspx

Tags: c#, .net, httphandler

I am working on a site that has a little flash gadget for which I do not have the source for and cannot change. The flash file is requesting 'file.php' on the server. I need to be able to provide file.aspx's content instead. I've written the following httpHandler:

```
namespace MyHandler
{
    public class UrlHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string vPath = context.Request.RawUrl;

            if (vPath.IndexOf("file.php", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
            {
                    context.Response.Redirect("file.aspx");
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

In IIS i've also mapped the *.php extension to use the .Net ISAPI Module in Handler Mappings. But when I navigate to file.php it just shows a 404 error.

Any help of fixing this, or another solution would be grately appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: This works when debugged in Visual Studio by the way. Just won't work on the live server.

Comment: Also, before anyone suggests I have <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.php" type="MyHandler.UrlHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers> in the web.confgi already.

Comment: what iis version are you using?

Comment: are those handlers in the webserver section?

Comment: There are asterisks in the above comment. Just wont show.

Comment: @Daniel - IIS7, there in the system.web section of the web config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the handler in the `system.webServer` section as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx

Comment: This was right. I was also adding a new project into a subfolder of the main site and had to move the HttpHandler DLL into the root bin folder to get it to work.

Comment: <handlers>
      <add name="PHPHandler" verb="*" 
        path="*.php" 
        type="MyHandler.UrlHandler, DLLFileName" 
        resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>